# I can't solve the dependency errror after trying various ways

Tags: android

I installed android studio synced with gradle files so my design editor came but after I connected my phone the code ran in my phone at first but when I closed android studio and opened it again it showed me `dependency error - could not download junit`.

I have tried invalidate and also tried deleting files from project folder, the error goes for once but again comes back so please give me permanent solution for this error. The android studio is latest version and coding with java

Comment: Could you share more details, error, screenshot, something more?

Comment: Did you try gradle toggle offline mode

Comment: I tried that also but the error can't seen to go permanently

Comment: Toggle kept on or off, the error doesn't goes

Comment: When I connect my phone with the studio a file named as build.gradle automatically opens up in studio and when I sync it shows me that it cannot download junit 4.12 hence cant resolve dependency